# Not able to deserialize json array object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am consuming an api in [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) that returns a json array that I want to deserialize to list using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` of Newtonsoft, but somehow it is not getting deserialized.

Web Api Result

```
[{
  'JobID': '5d7ff7c393c3511a9c165caa',
  'Name': '3dsmax-Demo-v2019 [BATCH MASTER]',
  'Date': '16.09.2019 23:59:45',
  'Frames': '1',
  'Status': 'Completed',
  'Priorty': 1,
  'Credit': '0,0327',
  'Estimated': '0,0654',
  'Progress': '100 %   (1/1)',
  'Cpu': '0'
} {
  'JobID': '5d80150b8b9da7134c7f7972',
  'Name': 'restoran [View01] (BATCH 1 of 13)',
  'Date': '17.09.2019 02:02:56',
  'Frames': '0',
  'Status': 'Completed',
  'Priorty': 1,
  'Credit': '1,1622',
  'Estimated': '2,3244',
  'Progress': '100 %   (1/1)',
  'Cpu': '0'
}]
```

C# Model Class

```
public class JobModel
{
    public string JobID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Frames { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string Priorty { get; set; }

    public string Credit { get; set; }

    public string Estimated { get; set; }

    public string Progress { get; set; }

    public string Cpu { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using the following to get it done

```
string data = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
var jobs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JobModel>>(data);
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions? Please post some detail.

Comment: I am getting  this exception  "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path '[0]', line 1, position 230"

Comment: There seems to be a comma missing in your api result between the objects. I don't think it is caused because of my cleanup, was it a copy paste error on your behalf?

Comment: Your JSON is malformed.  There should be a `,` between the two objects in the outer array: ``'Cpu': '0'
}, {
  'JobID': '5d80150b8b9da7134c7f7972',``.  Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dyzeko.  Fixed: https://dotnetfiddle.net/umBeWC

Comment: @Icepickle is there any way i can add , by myself as api owner is someone else and it have copied it as it is.

Comment: Exactly...  your JSON has an error in it.  Next time, rather than posting on StackOverflow, simply cut'n'paste your JSON into jsonlint.com and this will tell you if your JSON is valid.   If it's not... well...  you aren't going to get very far until you've fixed it.

Comment: No, you could make them aware of it. I mean, ofcourse you could do some manual editing by yourself, but that would be error prone. You could erase the starting `[` and ending `]` and split on `} {`, and then parse each result on its own, but like I said, that's very error prone

Comment: As mentioned above, there are online tools including https://jsonlint.com/ and https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ that can be used to validate that JSON is well-formed.  Ask whomever gave you that JSON file to ensure their JSON can be parsed successfully by these tools, fixing their code as necessary.

Comment: You could try a simple replace... `data = data.Replace("} {", "}, {")`  There are gotchas with doing that, but with what you've posted it will work.

Comment: @MikeGledhill  jsonlint.com site is marking this json  valid when i tested it over there and after that only i posted the question here

Comment: @NitinSingh are you certain? I just tried it and it failed. Double check the JSON in the post with what the API gave you.

Comment: @StevePak The jason is invalid but the site jsonlint.com is considering it as valid json.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  You need to take your JSON, replace the apostrophes with speechmark characters, and *then* cut'n'paste it into jsonlint.   And then it'll tell you that you're missing a comma...it says:     Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Answer (score 0):

JSON property names and non-numeric values should be in "" (doublequotation mark) instead of '' (sinlequotation mark).

Use another class to wrap collection of JobModel (it's a good practice but json should be changed too), e.g.:

```
class ResultModel
{
   public ICollection<JobModel> Jobs { get; set; }
}
// JSON:
{
   "Jobs": [
   {
    // class properties with values
   },
   {
    // class properties with values
   }]
}
```

and chang type for deserialize method:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel>(data);
```

If you can't change JSON then use JArray:

```
JArray jJobs = JArray.Parse(json);
```

and map JObject's JProperties on your class.